# Terminate python based on printed output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

In here, [Limit tweepy stream to a specific number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721567/limit-tweepy-stream-to-a-specific-number/30721672), I tried to stop a streaming script using tweepy but kept getting an error. I tried fixing the error as some people may have suggested but no luck.

I thought of another method of possibly terminating the script based on a the number of printed outputs. What I did is take the previous code and put into a function:

```
def streamer(location):
    ## same code here ##
    twitterStream.filter(locations=[\location) ## changed to match function##
```

Then I would call the function (i.e. `streamer(LA)`) where LA is predefined with a set of coordinates.

My question: Is it possible to terminate the function `streamer` based on the number it outputs without changing the function itself (due to persisting error)?

Answer (score 0):

you could use [`quit()`](http://ocs.python.org/3.1/library/constants.html#quit) but that also terminates the whole session.

You also need to add your streamdata to a variable somewhere.
If I am correct you will get a constant stream of Json items, so just add them to a list and then use the length of the list. Then use twitterstream.disconnect() if you got your amount of outputs.

Comment: `'Stream' object has no attribute 'count'`

Comment: sorry I meant the counter variable of the listener class from your previous post, I'll edit that.

Comment: I did add it to the class, that's where I got the error from.

Comment: ahh, yeah sorry for the derp, I was just working with TCP connections and .NET. I edited my post for a better answer.