# python - Traceback (most recent call last): ...

Tags: python, twitter, anaconda, tweepy

I try to collecting data from Twitter with Python and tweepy.

My code is :

```
import tweepy

consumer_key="..."
consumer_secret="..."
access_key = "..."
access_secret = "..."


class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print (status.text)

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
sapi.filter(track=['capital'], async=True)
```

In my console, python return :

```
RT @gucamo74: @rubenuria eso es muy difícil. El Sevilla no tiene el halo protector arbitral de los equipos de la capital y del Barcelona.
RT @TonySantanaZA: @woznyjs On Macro scale, we failed 2 create Corporate stability, 4 investing Companies. Hence Capital flight,2 other mor… "Pour ne pas se faire rouler"...... #Capital
```

So it's fine but after few tweets he show me this message :

```
Exception in thread Thread-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 286, in _run
    raise
RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise
```

Do you have an idea why? I want that the steam doesn't stop before I ask him.

Comment: +1 for the single most generic subject line on stackoverflow! ... but it would be nice to change it to a quick summary of your problem.

Comment: I think you have an installation problem. That's a python 2.x script yet pythnon3.5 tweepy is running.

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney, I have Python 3 install. Do you think I need to install python 2 ?

Comment: `print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code` is a python 2.x style print statement that will raise an error on python 3. If you change it to `print('Encountered error with status code:', status_code, file=sys.stderr)` - and similarly with the other print statements - you may avoid the problematic tweepy error handler.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on this post :

### [Unraised exception using Tweepy and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869442/unraised-exception-using-tweepy-and-mysql/28871066#28871066)

By checking tweepy/streaming.py at https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/streaming.py it seems there is a bug in tweepy in the way exceptions are handled, spefically

```
if exception:
        # call a handler first so that the exception can be logged.
        self.listener.on_exception(exception)
        raise
```

This `raise` should be `raise exception`

That's magic but It work...